# CakePHP 3: A form control doesn't show its value with default or value

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

A form control doesn't show its value
although a value element in input tag is set.(checked output html code)

Here are some example as below.

```
// ExampleController.php
class ExampleController extends AppController
{
    public function add()
    {
        ...
        $example = $this->Examples->newEntity();
        $this->set('example', $example);
    }
}


// Example/add.ctp
<?= $this->Form->create(
    $example,
    [
        'id' => 'test-example',
        'url' => [
            'controller' => 'Example',
            'action' => 'add',
        ]
    ]) ?>
...
<?= $this->Form->text('title', [
    'label' => false,
    'placeholder' => 'title',
    'id' => 'title',
    'default' => 'test'
]); ?>

// output html
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title" id="title" required="required" value="test">
```

Comment: That sounds more like a HTML, and/or maybe JS problem. Start with investigating the latter, turn of JavaScript and see if it makes any difference. Also check (and maybe show) the complete generated form HTML, and make sure that the input is placed where you expect it to be, and that it's not maybe a duplicate that you're looking at.

Comment: You are right. I've found that values are overwritten by JS which I never expected. Thank you for your advice.